# If an Observable error fires, does the complete event not fire?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rxjs

I'm wrapping an callback API using `Observable.create`.  This is the implementation:

```
  complete: result => {
    if (result.errors.length > 0) {
      observer.error(result.errors);
    } else {
      observer.next(result);
    }
    observer.complete();
  }
```

Per my testing it seems that when `observer.error` is fired, then `observer.complete` will not fire.

Also when `observer.next` does fire, then `observer.complete` also fires.

This is what I'm seeing.  Looking at my implementation I thought that `observer.complete` would fire, even though there is an error, but perhaps RxJS switches it off?

Comment: Yes, it switches off, see ["In an Observable Execution, zero to infinite Next notifications may be delivered. If either an Error or Complete notification is delivered, then nothing else can be delivered afterwards."](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#observer)

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for confirming!

Comment: If you want to provide the official answer I can give you credit ...